# Query optimization?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, query-optimization, query-performance

Hello guys i had seprate 12 queries and some c# code to get the data formatted on the page, but now we are converted those pages to the SSRS reports. I have built the stored procedure which is combination of the 12 queries and some new additional queries to format the data as we want on the ssrs report. Now the new stored procedure is taking more time than the old page  here is my query can any optimization possible on the following stored procedure any help would be great .

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetHistoryByYear_Get] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here    
@Year AS VARCHAR(4),
@PreYear AS VARCHAR(4)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;  
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

SELECT *  
INTO #tempCustVol
FROM 
    ( 
SELECT *  FROM 
    (   
        SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT @Year AS 'Year',Company, Customer,SUM(Jan) AS Jan, SUM(Feb) AS Feb, SUM(Mar) As Mar, SUM(Apr) AS Apr, SUM(May) AS May, SUM(Jun) AS Jun, SUM(Jul) AS Jul, SUM(Aug) AS Aug, SUM(Sep) AS Sep, SUM(Oct) AS Oct, SUM(Nov) AS Nov, SUM(Dec) AS Dec    
        ,(SUM(Jan) + SUM(Feb) + SUM(Mar) + SUM(Apr) + SUM(May) + SUM(Jun) + SUM(Jul) + SUM(Aug) + SUM(Sep) + SUM(Oct) + SUM(Nov) + SUM(Dec) ) AS YearlyTotal    
        FROM(    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, SUM(Records) AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@Year + '0101' and datercvd <= @Year + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '01' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, SUM(RECORDS) AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@Year + '0101' and datercvd <= @Year + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '02' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, SUM(RECORDS) As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@Year + '0101' and datercvd <= @Year + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '03' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, SUM(RECORDS) As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@Year + '0101' and datercvd <= @Year + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '04' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, SUM(RECORDS) As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@Year + '0101' and datercvd <= @Year + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '05' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, SUM(RECORDS) As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@Year + '0101' and datercvd <= @Year + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '06' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, SUM(RECORDS) As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@Year + '0101' and datercvd <= @Year + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '07' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, SUM(RECORDS) As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@Year + '0101' and datercvd <= @Year + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '08' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, SUM(RECORDS) As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@Year + '0101' and datercvd <= @Year + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '09' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, SUM(RECORDS) As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@Year + '0101' and datercvd <= @Year + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '10' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, SUM(RECORDS) As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@Year + '0101' and datercvd <= @Year + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '11' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, SUM(RECORDS) As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@Year + '0101' and datercvd <= @Year + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '12' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            ) F    
        GROUP BY Company, Customer
        ) AS ALLDATA

        UNION 

        SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT @PreYear AS 'Year',Company, Customer,SUM(Jan) AS Jan, SUM(Feb) AS Feb, SUM(Mar) As Mar, SUM(Apr) AS Apr, SUM(May) AS May, SUM(Jun) AS Jun, SUM(Jul) AS Jul, SUM(Aug) AS Aug, SUM(Sep) AS Sep, SUM(Oct) AS Oct, SUM(Nov) AS Nov, SUM(Dec) AS Dec    
        ,(SUM(Jan) + SUM(Feb) + SUM(Mar) + SUM(Apr) + SUM(May) + SUM(Jun) + SUM(Jul) + SUM(Aug) + SUM(Sep) + SUM(Oct) + SUM(Nov) + SUM(Dec) ) AS YearlyTotal    
        FROM(    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, SUM(Records) AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@PreYear + '0101' and datercvd <= @PreYear + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '01' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, SUM(RECORDS) AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@PreYear + '0101' and datercvd <= @PreYear + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '02' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, SUM(RECORDS) As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@PreYear + '0101' and datercvd <= @PreYear + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '03' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, SUM(RECORDS) As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@PreYear + '0101' and datercvd <= @PreYear + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '04' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, SUM(RECORDS) As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@PreYear + '0101' and datercvd <= @PreYear + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '05' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, SUM(RECORDS) As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@PreYear + '0101' and datercvd <= @PreYear + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '06' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, SUM(RECORDS) As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@PreYear + '0101' and datercvd <= @PreYear + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '07' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, SUM(RECORDS) As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@PreYear + '0101' and datercvd <= @PreYear + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '08' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, SUM(RECORDS) As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@PreYear + '0101' and datercvd <= @PreYear + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '09' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, SUM(RECORDS) As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@PreYear + '0101' and datercvd <= @PreYear + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '10' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, SUM(RECORDS) As Nov, 0 As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@PreYear + '0101' and datercvd <= @PreYear + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '11' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            UNION    
            SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, SUM(RECORDS) As Dec    
            FROM(    
                select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@PreYear + '0101' and datercvd <= @PreYear + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '12' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
                )  AS T    
            GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
            ) F    
        GROUP BY Company, Customer
        ) AS ALLDATA
    ) AS TEMPDATA
    ) AS data

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM #tempCustVol
UNION
SELECT 
    @PreYear AS [Year],null,null,COALESCE(SUM(Jan),0),COALESCE(SUM(Feb),0),COALESCE(SUM(Mar),0),COALESCE(SUM(Apr),0),
    COALESCE(SUM(May),0),COALESCE(SUM(Jun),0),COALESCE(SUM(Jul),0),COALESCE(SUM(Aug),0),COALESCE(SUM(Sep),0),COALESCE(SUM(Oct),0),
    COALESCE(SUM(Nov),0),COALESCE(SUM(Dec),0),COALESCE((SUM(Jan) + SUM(Feb) + SUM(Mar) + SUM(Apr) + SUM(May) + SUM(Jun) + SUM(Jul) + SUM(Aug) + SUM(Sep) + SUM(Oct) + SUM(Nov) + SUM(Dec) ),0) AS YearlyTotal
FROM #tempCustVol
WHERE [Year] = @PreYear
)AS DA
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN Company is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    Company,[Year]

DROP TABLE #tempCustVol
END
```

any help would be great i have indexed the tables and tables have lots of data it takes near about the 10 to 12 min to execute is there any way i can minimize it. and it's the SQL SERVER 2008 database

**UPDATE**

---

This is my updated stored procedure

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @Year AS VARCHAR(4),
@PreYear AS VARCHAR(4)
SET  @Year='2013'
SET @PreYear='2012'
SET NOCOUNT ON;  
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

SELECT *  
INTO #tempCustVol
FROM 
    ( 
SELECT *  FROM 
    (   
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT @Year AS 'Year',Company, Customer,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '01' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '02' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '03' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Mar,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '04' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Apr,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '05' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS May,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '06' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '07' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Jul,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '08' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Aug,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '09' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Sep,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '10' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '11' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Nov,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '12' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Dec,
            SUM(Records) AS YearlyTotal    
        FROM  vwjmrep
        WHERE datercvd >=@Year + '0101' and datercvd <= @Year + '1231'  AND Company IS NOT NULL 
        GROUP BY Company, Customer
        ) AS ALLDATA
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT @PreYear AS 'Year',Company, Customer,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '01' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '02' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '03' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Mar,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '04' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Apr,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '05' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS May,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '06' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '07' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Jul,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '08' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Aug,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '09' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Sep,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '10' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '11' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Nov,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '12' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Dec,
            SUM(Records) AS YearlyTotal    
        FROM  vwjmrep
        WHERE datercvd >=@PreYear + '0101' and datercvd <= @PreYear + '1231'  AND Company IS NOT NULL 
        GROUP BY Company, Customer
        ) AS ALLDATA
    ) AS TEMPDATA
    ) AS data

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM #tempCustVol
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    @PreYear AS [Year],null,null,COALESCE(SUM(Jan),0),COALESCE(SUM(Feb),0),COALESCE(SUM(Mar),0),COALESCE(SUM(Apr),0),
    COALESCE(SUM(May),0),COALESCE(SUM(Jun),0),COALESCE(SUM(Jul),0),COALESCE(SUM(Aug),0),COALESCE(SUM(Sep),0),COALESCE(SUM(Oct),0),
    COALESCE(SUM(Nov),0),COALESCE(SUM(Dec),0),COALESCE((SUM(Jan) + SUM(Feb) + SUM(Mar) + SUM(Apr) + SUM(May) + SUM(Jun) + SUM(Jul) + SUM(Aug) + SUM(Sep) + SUM(Oct) + SUM(Nov) + SUM(Dec) ),0) AS YearlyTotal
FROM #tempCustVol
WHERE [Year] = @PreYear
)AS DA
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN Company is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    Company,[Year]

DROP TABLE #tempCustVol
END
```

which is still takes time but is there any more optimization possible thanks

Comment: Have you tried the Query Optimizer/SQL Index tuning options in SSMS yet? That is usually a good place to start.

Comment: I don't like this structure, but the first help. Change UNION to UNION ALL (your sets are different), you haven't duplicate.

Comment: @JohnFx Thaks that i tried .

Comment: @MitchWheat yaa! i know !

Comment: @JoeTaras yes that reduced the time by some secs thanks for help but is there any other structure i can follow to get the result as quickly  as possible

Comment: i) use union all
ii)remove insert and temp table
iii) you are using so mauch string in where condition.if possible change to int.
iv) SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) in ('03','04','05').such select can be combine into one.In fact you almost all can be combine to one.
your query can be more than half the size.first you do all the correction and show the change

Comment: @KumarHarsh thanks i did the updates and the execution time cut down was amazing thanks

Comment: @Curiosity: remove SELECT * FROM ... AS ALLDATA. You have put an unuseful level after group by. The same thing for TEMPDATA. You can remove in total 3 SELECT * FROM

Comment: What's the datatype of `datercvd`?  If it's an actual date/timestamp type, switch out the `SUBSTRING(...)`s for `DATEPART(...)`  Note that I don't expect this to make it _faster_, but it will be safer, and more obvious what you're doing.  Also, when dealing with date/time/timestamps in SQL Server, [please do not use inclusive upper-bounds](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thanks but `Datercvd` is `varchar` type so i cant apply the `DATEPART(...)`so anyway thanks

Comment: Frankly SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM #tempCustVol onward is not required.you can populate List without "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM #tempCustVol....." and can do rest of the manipulation on List.
Don't do everything in proc in such situation .Also I am unware of your requirement .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can try replace this

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT @Year AS 'Year',Company, Customer,SUM(Jan) AS Jan, SUM(Feb) AS Feb, SUM(Mar) As Mar, SUM(Apr) AS Apr, SUM(May) AS May, SUM(Jun) AS Jun, SUM(Jul) AS Jul, SUM(Aug) AS Aug, SUM(Sep) AS Sep, SUM(Oct) AS Oct, SUM(Nov) AS Nov, SUM(Dec) AS Dec    
    ,(SUM(Jan) + SUM(Feb) + SUM(Mar) + SUM(Apr) + SUM(May) + SUM(Jun) + SUM(Jul) + SUM(Aug) + SUM(Sep) + SUM(Oct) + SUM(Nov) + SUM(Dec) ) AS YearlyTotal    
    FROM(    
        SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, SUM(Records) AS Jan, 0 AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
        FROM(    
            select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@Year + '0101' and datercvd <= @Year + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '01' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
            )  AS T    
        GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd    
        UNION    
        SELECT Company, Customer, DateRcvd, 0 AS Jan, SUM(RECORDS) AS Feb, 0 As Mar, 0 As Apr, 0 As May, 0 As Jun, 0 As Jul, 0 As Aug, 0 As Sep, 0 As Oct, 0 As Nov, 0 As Dec    
        FROM(    
            select * from vwjmrep where datercvd >=@Year + '0101' and datercvd <= @Year + '1231' AND SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '02' AND Company IS NOT NULL    
            )  AS T    
        GROUP BY Company, Customer, DateRcvd   

GROUP BY Company, Customer
```

with this

```
 SELECT @Year AS 'Year',Company, Customer,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '01' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '02' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
    ...,
    SUM(Records) AS YearlyTotal    
    FROM  vwjmrep
WHERE datercvd >=@Year + '0101' and datercvd <= @Year + '1231'  AND Company IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY Company, Customer
```

At least, there will be less Table Scans.

Comment: Thanks mate it helped a lot it nearly cut down time of execution to the some seconds thanks again

Comment: Given this is SQL Server, you really don't want to use inclusive upper-bounds with [date/time/timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Also, you can calculate the yearly total along with the monthly totals, you don't need a separate wrap for that.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Hi. I didn't get what is the point of your comment. The answer is concerned with optimization of the given query and it actually must reduce number of Table Scans by 12. I don't know why author uses this conditions for dates because I don't know what is th data type of `datercvd`. I just copy-pasted author's code for this.

Comment: Er, sorry about the 'overall total' part (comment copied from below). As for dealing with dates - while it's true that I certainly suspected that `datercvd` was character, it's best to deal with it as if had the potential to _become_ an actual date/timestamp type (given the bounding forms are in a safely translatable format).  This way, the type of the column could be safely changed, without affecting the query; however, for the current version, changing the type of the column will necessitate also changing the query (because the upper bound will not select _all_ of the given day).

Comment: @Curiosity I think, adding of index on vwjmrep (datercvd) can improve performance.

Comment: @Igor Thanks, I  have already done the indexing so with your help i have cut down lots of execution time i am marking it as answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetHistoryByYear_Get] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here    
@Year AS VARCHAR(4),
@PreYear AS VARCHAR(4)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;  
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

SELECT *  
INTO #tempCustVol
FROM 
( 
SELECT *
        , Jan + Feb + Mar + Apr + May + Jun + Jul + Aug + Sep + Oct + Nov + [Dec] AS YearlyTotal 
FROM (
SELECT @Year AS 'Year', Company, Customer,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '01' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Jan,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '02' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Feb,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '03' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Mar,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '04' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Apr,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '05' THEN Records ELSE 0)) May,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '06' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Jun,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '07' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Jul,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '08' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Aug,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '09' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Sep,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '10' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Oct,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '11' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Nov,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '12' THEN Records ELSE 0)) [Dec]
FROM vwjmrep
WHERE   Company IS NOT NULL
        AND (datercvd >=@Year + '0101' AND datercvd <= @Year + '1231')
GROUP BY Company, Customer
UNION ALL
SELECT @PreYear AS 'Year', Company, Customer,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '01' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Jan,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '02' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Feb,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '03' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Mar,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '04' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Apr,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '05' THEN Records ELSE 0)) May,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '06' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Jun,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '07' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Jul,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '08' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Aug,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '09' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Sep,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '10' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Oct,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '11' THEN Records ELSE 0)) Nov,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '12' THEN Records ELSE 0)) [Dec]
FROM vwjmrep
WHERE   Company IS NOT NULL
        AND (datercvd >=@PreYear + '0101' AND datercvd <= @PreYear + '1231')
GROUP BY Company, Customer
) x
) ALLDATA
...Rest of the code here
```

Comment: Given this is SQL Server, you really don't want to use inclusive upper-bounds with [date/time/timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Also, you can calculate the yearly total along with the monthly totals, you don't need a separate wrap for that.

Answer (score 0):

about my last comment:- I still go by it.Doing some stuff in sql and some in C# specially when query is so heavy .also your query do not have pagination.So no optmize query can help if it more than 100 rows.Also you hv to use index.
Ok man check this out,if its not running then tell

```
;With CTE as
(SELECT @Year AS 'Year',Company, Customer,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '01' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '02' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '03' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Mar,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '04' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Apr,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '05' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS May,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '06' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '07' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Jul,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '08' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Aug,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '09' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Sep,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '10' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '11' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Nov,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '12' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Dec,
            SUM(Records) AS YearlyTotal    
        FROM  vwjmrep
        WHERE datercvd >=@Year + '0101' and datercvd <= @Year + '1231'  AND Company IS NOT NULL 
        GROUP BY Company, Customer
Union All

SELECT @PreYear AS 'Year',Company, Customer,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '01' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '02' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '03' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Mar,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '04' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Apr,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '05' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS May,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '06' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '07' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Jul,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '08' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Aug,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '09' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Sep,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '10' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '11' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Nov,
            SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DateRcvd,5,2) = '12' THEN Records ELSE 0 END) AS Dec,
            SUM(Records) AS YearlyTotal    
        FROM  vwjmrep
        WHERE datercvd >=@PreYear + '0101' and datercvd <= @PreYear + '1231'  AND Company IS NOT NULL 
        GROUP BY Company, Customer
)
,CTE1 as
(Select * from cte
union all
SELECT 
    @PreYear AS [Year],null,null,COALESCE(SUM(Jan),0),COALESCE(SUM(Feb),0),COALESCE(SUM(Mar),0),COALESCE(SUM(Apr),0),
    COALESCE(SUM(May),0),COALESCE(SUM(Jun),0),COALESCE(SUM(Jul),0),COALESCE(SUM(Aug),0),COALESCE(SUM(Sep),0),COALESCE(SUM(Oct),0),
    COALESCE(SUM(Nov),0),COALESCE(SUM(Dec),0),COALESCE((SUM(Jan) + SUM(Feb) + SUM(Mar) + SUM(Apr) + SUM(May) + SUM(Jun) + SUM(Jul) + SUM(Aug) + SUM(Sep) + SUM(Oct) + SUM(Nov) + SUM(Dec) ),0) AS YearlyTotal
FROM cte
WHERE [Year] = @PreYear
)
select * from cte1
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN Company is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    Company,[Year]
```